# show that the von Neumann universes $R_{\omega+ \alpha}$ have cardinality $\beth_\alpha$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Trying to show that the von Neumann universes $R_{\omega+ \alpha}$ have cardinality $\beth_\alpha$.

Here is my attempt:

Proof by induction on $\alpha$.
For $\alpha = 0$, $|R_{\omega+ 0}| = |R_{\omega}| = \omega =  \beth_0$.

For $\alpha = \beta+1$, $|R_{\omega+ \alpha}| = |\mathcal{P}(R_{\omega+\beta})| = {2}^{|R_{\omega+\beta}|}$. By the IH, we have ${2}^{|R_{\omega+\beta}|} = {2}^{ \beth_\beta} =  \beth_{\alpha}$. Hence, $|R_{\omega+ \alpha}| =  \beth_{\alpha}$.

For $\alpha = \bigcup\limits_{\beta < \alpha} \beta$, $\beth_\alpha = \sup\limits_{\beta < \alpha}\{ \beth_\beta \}$. By the IH, $|R_{\omega+\beta}| =  \beth_\beta$ for all $\beta < \alpha$. So, $\sup\limits_{\beta < \alpha}\{  |R_{\omega+\beta}| \} = \sup\limits_{ \beta < \alpha}\{  \beth_\beta \}$.

I'm not sure how to finish the limit case though. Any help would be great.

Comment: Check the definition of $\beth_\alpha$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$.

Comment: So we could say, $|R_{\omega+\alpha}| = \sup\limits_{\beta < \alpha}\{  |R_{\omega+\beta}| \} = \sup\limits_{\beta < \alpha}\{ \beth_\beta \} = \beth_\alpha$. Correct?

Comment: That’s right: the definition of the $\beth$ number at limit ordinals does exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: You’re welcome.